# Linear gradient with multiple colors on Mozilla is blurry

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, linear-gradients

I want my element to have a sharp background gradient with multiple colors.
On Chrome it's working fine, but on Firefox it has blurry edges on transition.

Here are examples on:

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

How can I make it to work on Firefox?

```css
.footer::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 11px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') 0 0/100% 11px no-repeat;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #ffd503 16.6%,#f36f21 16.6%,#f36f21 33.2%,#da2128 33.2%,#da2128 49.8%,#009066 49.8%,#009066 66.4%,#b51e83 66.4%,#b51e83 83.8%,#005a9e 83.8%) 0 0/100% 11px no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #ffd503 16.6%,#f36f21 16.6%,#f36f21 33.2%,#da2128 33.2%,#da2128 49.8%,#009066 49.8%,#009066 66.4%,#b51e83 66.4%,#b51e83 83.8%,#005a9e 83.8%) 0 0/100% 11px no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffd503 16.6%,#f36f21 16.6%,#f36f21 33.2%,#da2128 33.2%,#da2128 49.8%,#009066 49.8%,#009066 66.4%,#b51e83 66.4%,#b51e83 83.8%,#005a9e 83.8%) 0 0/100% 11px no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 150px, 100% 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround and not a fix.

In my environment I actually observe the opposite result in a js fiddle. On Mac Sierra running FF 54.0.1 I get crisp transitions. However, on Chrome 60.0.3112.101 I get fuzzy transitions. So, results could vary depending on the enviorment.

Since this isn't supposed to be a continuous gradient allow me to propose a different solution that will render crisp in any browser. Basically, create a container to hold the solid color boxes, give it a relative position and place your element with an absolute position inside the container.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
<div class="box4"></div>
<div class="box5"></div>
<div class="box6"></div>
<div class="my-element">my element</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {width:100%;margin:50px 0px 50px 0px;position:relative;left:0px;right:0px;}
.container div {float:left;height:12px;width:16.6%;}
.box1 {background-color:#ffd503;}
.box2 {background-color:#f36f21;}
.box3 {background-color:#da2128;}
.box4 {background-color:#009066;}
.box5 {background-color:#b51e83;}
.box6 {background-color:#005a9e;}

.my-element {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jfeferman/rpfkpyvj/